# Thread Suicide on Shutdown? stopping java.util.Timer instance

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `java.util.Timer` running at a fixed interval. I have added a `Runtime#addShutdownHook` and it shuts down when the VM ends normally or abnormally. However, it keeps the VM alive when a `main` terminates, unless I insist by doing a `System.exit` in the `main`. **Is there any way for me to check if I'm the last `Thread` standing, or some other way to avoid altering a `main` that would exit normally on finish?**

<sub>**Note:** I know a lot of people believe that `java.util.Timer` is deprecated (it's not), but unless your alternative helps me solve this problem...</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the timer using one of the constructor overloads which allows you to specify whether to use a daemon thread: pass `true` in as the argument, so that it will run on a daemon thread, which won't prevent the VM from shutting down.